# How to display loading animation when transitioning between fragmens?

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, android-animation, loading

I am still in fragment, for display new fragment using the code:

```
CatalogFragment catalogFragment = new CatalogFragment();
var fragmentManager = Activity.SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
fragmentManager.Replace(Resource.Id.flContent, (SupportFragment)catalogFragment);
fragmentManager.AddToBackStack(null);
fragmentManager.Commit();
```

How to display loading animation (such as "animated circle" or gif) when transitioning between fragmens? 
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

For animated circle you should put a progress dialog before replacing the fragment. After that you should disable it in new fragment. But fragments can be animated natively. You should checkout this link. https://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html

Comment: I tried it, but progress dialog displayed only after loaded new fragment.